# Expanding PolyGamma function error

Tags: bugs, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 6.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.3.0**

---

For large half-integer arguments of the `PolyGamma[]` function, `FunctionExpand[]` or `FullSimplify[]` return strange, error-like, expressions

```
FunctionExpand[PolyGamma[0, 1051/2]]
(* => ... + System`PolyGammaDump`res$14430 *)
```

or even

```
(* Hold[RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[
    System`PolyGammaDump`res$5680]], 
      Head[System`PolyGammaDump`res$5680] =!= DirectedInfinity]] *)
```

These, combined further with simple algebraic expressions like `+`, give

```
FunctionExpand[PolyGamma[0, 1051/2] + 1]
(* => ... + Hold[Fail] *)
```

(why `Hold[Fail]`? and not some message?) This "error" does not appear when I decrease the argument of `PolyGamma[]`:

```
FunctionExpand[PolyGamma[0, 21/2]]
(* 62075752/14549535 - EulerGamma - Log[4] *)
```

Is this a bug of my *Mathematica* version (10.0.2.0 for Mac OS X)? Recurrence identities for polygamma should be implemented in *Mathematica* (compare output of `PolyGamma[0, 10/2 + 1] - PolyGamma[0, 10/2]` and `PolyGamma[0, 2001/2 + 1] - PolyGamma[0, 2001/2]`); how can one trace that bug and possibly overcome it?

Comment: Very interesting. For reference, do you get similar errors for `Gamma[]` and `HarmonicNumber[]`?

Comment: `Gamma[]` is just evaluated, for `HarmonicNumber[]` I do get the same as for `PolyGamma[]`.

Comment: A clear bug, I think; somebody botched the recursive relation behind the scenes. Can you try `Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity}, FunctionExpand[PolyGamma[1051/2]]]`?

Comment: This seems to work. Can you please give (if possible) a more detailed answer below and possibly a mechanism 'behind the scenes'? Alternative solution to this bug is to apply a recurrence to `PolyGamma[]` or `HarmonicNumber[]` by hand.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not at a computer to test things out more fully and thus write a substantial answer; I merely guessed based on what you've shown me. What is clear is that the internal recursive implementation was not written to account for large integer arguments. I will add the [tag:bugs] tag now, but let's also wait for other people to test this out.

Comment: This seems to go back a while. I've filed a bug report with the developers.

Comment: With Mathematica 10.2 on Mac I get same error. Workaround given by @J. M. works. Alternatively, you can get numeric result with `FunctionExpand[PolyGamma[0,1051/2.]]`

Comment: Sorry, I haven't  mentioned that I'm interested in exact values and a way to overcome this bug not in approximate (numerical) results.

Comment: I've started to push this further and the solution by @J. M. does not work for very large arguments (the kernel just quits), e.g. try `Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity}, FunctionExpand[PolyGamma[0, a]]]` for `a=4501/2` and `a=4601/2`.

Comment: @mmal, I think that the kernel couldn't handle that much recursion at that point. You may have to resort to evaluating explicit `Sum[]`s instead.

Comment: Fixed in the development version today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by ilian, this has been fixed in the newest version. For those stuck with older versions, a workaround can be devised based on [this expansion formula](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma/17/01/02/0001/), like so:

```
a = 1051/2;
n = IntegerPart[a]; f = FractionalPart[a];
PolyGamma[f] + Sum[1/(f + k), {k, 0, n - 1}, Method -> "Procedural"]
// FunctionExpand
```

This works even for the larger `a = 4601/2` case, unlike the suggestion I gave in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

As previously mentioned in the comments, this bug has been fixed as of *Mathematica* 10.3.

```
$Version

(* "10.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)" *)

FunctionExpand[PolyGamma[0, 1051/2]]

(* 1285419799936525483590440356485913118557238953850917571655841\
5741182979315173079330077832682124967619286005471667823256760099546705\
2891030373156621089354809760128773005810025097953873373875179741234456\
9187486859122888279655863758285716796306889323506583432571529367704503\
6137729023370199592517121547190898489561519446980549309597633794551282\
8024779606014776869981600684213070729430041879996083178849511286173189\
91345788279487197852589070073000030156838138/
  15624578896737929535308911953771213336402116274975379996559013353031\
1680190991120771924495781500410869490340481605874727401745947540728422\
2556840660803953943256878960592583459598665600326021616974229885783431\
2790170314522959586741781679470734395597442825041097450304608994258061\
5845822338517884531761963978132838586622754530461858355206268627504641\
8438386432184286804056434659183179146119622607050759848035815087097489\
678659193191774142898224573450093125 - EulerGamma - Log[4] *)

FunctionExpand[HarmonicNumber[1051/2 - 1] - EulerGamma]

(* 12854197999365254835904403564859131185572389538509175716558415\
7411829793151730793300778326821249676192860054716678232567600995467052\
8910303731566210893548097601287730058100250979538733738751797412344569\
1874868591228882796558637582857167963068893235065834325715293677045036\
1377290233701995925171215471908984895615194469805493095976337945512828\
0247796060147768699816006842130707294300418799960831788495112861731899\
1345788279487197852589070073000030156838138/
  15624578896737929535308911953771213336402116274975379996559013353031\
1680190991120771924495781500410869490340481605874727401745947540728422\
2556840660803953943256878960592583459598665600326021616974229885783431\
2790170314522959586741781679470734395597442825041097450304608994258061\
5845822338517884531761963978132838586622754530461858355206268627504641\
8438386432184286804056434659183179146119622607050759848035815087097489\
678659193191774142898224573450093125 - EulerGamma - Log[4] *)

FunctionExpand[PolyGamma[0, 9999/2]] // N

(* 8.51699 *)
```

Comment: Is `HarmonicNumber[]` also covered by this fix?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, example added.